# Prevent Escaping of Title Attribute in outputLink

Tags: java, html, jsf, escaping

I have a client who is vehement that I use the title attribute of a link to put a byline that includes the registered trademark symbol "®".  I have a very limited ability to modify their code, which basically leaves me with two options, pass the escape sequence &reg; and don't escape the output, or pass the symbol itself and let JSF handle the escape sequences.  I'd prefer the former, and have tried it in several variations, and remain completely unable to prevent the escaping of the sequence so I always end up with &reg; in the title.

```
<h:outputLink 
    value="#{url}"
    title="#{stringContainingEscapeSequence}"
    escape="false"
>
    <h:outputText value="#{myLinkText}" />
</h:outputLink>

<h:outputLink 
    value="#{url}"
>
    <f:attribute name="title" value="#{stringContainingEscapeSequence}" escape="false"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{myLinkText}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

Neither of the above result in an unescaped value being passed to the page, and when I insert the ® symbol in raw form, I end up with "À®" instead of just the symbol.

TL;DR:  Does anyone know how to stop JSF from autoescaping the value of a title attribute?  I know java on the back end, but I don't use JSF.

Answer (score 1):

> ... and when I insert the ® symbol in raw form, I end up with "À®" instead of just the symbol.

That sounds to me like a charset mismatch; e.g. the raw bytes are represented in one character encoding, but the browser thinks that a different character encoding should be used.

If you can't figure out a way to prevent the autoescaping, try fixing the character encoding mismatch.

Comment: Or a wrong additional character in the string (since the ® is visible)